# Vuejs computed filter on API response not working

Tags: json, vue.js, search, filter, computed-properties

I have an API response I'm trying to run a search filter through, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I feel like it's an issue with how the response is being returned, I've tried parsing/stringify, but I get the same error every time. The error I receive is:

> Error in render: "TypeError: this.heroList.filter is not a function"

My HTML:

```
<input class="searchbar" placeholder="Search..." type="text" v-model="search" />

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" v-for="(a, index) in filteredHeroList" :key="index">
    <img
      @click="selectedHero(a)"
      class="row full-image"
      :src="'http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/' + a.shortName + '_full.png'"
      alt="People"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Data:

```
data() {
 return {
  search: "",
  heroList: [],
};
```

},

My Axios request:

```
getHeroes() {
  axios
    .get(`https://api.stratz.com/api/v1/Hero`)
    .then(response => {
      this.heroList = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

Response I'm trying to filter:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "npc_dota_hero_antimage",
  "displayName": "Anti-Mage",
  "shortName": "antimage",
  "abilities": [
    {
      "slot": 1,
      "abilityId": 5003
    },
    {
      "slot": 2,
      "abilityId": 5004
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "roleId": 0,
      "level": 3
    },
    {
      "roleId": 1,
      "level": 3
    }
  ],
  "talents": [
    {
      "slot": 0,
      "gameVersionId": 131,
      "abilityId": 6137
    },
    {
      "slot": 1,
      "gameVersionId": 131,
      "abilityId": 6119
    }
  ],
  "stat": {
    "gameVersionId": 131,
    "enabled": true,
    "heroUnlockOrder": 1,
    "team": true,
    "cmEnabled": true,
    "newPlayerEnabled": true,
    "attackType": "Melee",
    "startingArmor": 2.36,
    "startingMagicArmor": 25,
    "startingDamageMin": 29,
    "startingDamageMax": 33,
    "attackRate": 1.4,
    "attackAnimationPoint": 0.3,
    "attackAcquisitionRange": 600,
    "attackRange": 150,
    "primaryAttribute": "agi",
    "heroPrimaryAttribute": 1,
    "strengthBase": 23,
    "strengthGain": 1.3,
    "intelligenceBase": 12,
    "intelligenceGain": 1.8,
    "agilityBase": 24,
    "agilityGain": 3,
    "hpRegen": 0.25,
    "mpRegen": 0,
    "moveSpeed": 310,
    "moveTurnRate": 0.5,
    "hpBarOffset": 0,
    "visionDaytimeRange": 1800,
    "visionNighttimeRange": 800,
    "complexity": 1
  },
  "language": {
    "heroId": 1,
    "gameVersionId": 131,
    "languageId": 0,
    "displayName": "Anti-Mage",
    "bio": "random bio string",
    "hype": "random hype string"
  },
  "aliases": [
    "am"
  ]
}
```

My Computed filter:

```
computed: {
filteredHeroList() {
  return this.heroList.filter(hero => {
    return (
      hero.shortname
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()));
  });
}
```

Comment: So upon looking further for some reason my heroList is returning as an object and not an array. Any idea why?

Comment: look ur "this".heroList    "this" is vue   or  other

Comment: @Mars.Tsai I'm not sure what you mean exactly

Answer (score 0):

[image: response]

This ended up fixing my issue.